# How to update a file in google drive using Google drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, apex-code, salesforce-service-cloud

I am trying to update a file on google drive using google drive API. The body content does not work. I am trying with google simulator but do not know how to give the updated content in Body Request here. Below is the screenshot (In Parent attribute "id" is the Folder ID).

[Google simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfym0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update).

For the request:

> This method provides media upload functionality through two separate
>   URIs. For more details, see the document on [media
>   upload](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads).
>
> - Upload URI, for media upload requests:   `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/fileId`
> - Metadata URI, for metadata-only requests:   `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId`

Check these [examples](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/examples/) if it helps.

Comment: Yo I've been looking no these sites and theyu only seem to show how to update metadata but  I can't find what request body parameter is needed for the actual new content??